# Subtracting one row from another in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've seen a few examples on how to subtract rows in a table, such as:
[mysql subtract two rows from column and places into an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038767/mysql-subtract-two-rows-from-column-and-places-into-an-alias)

All examples that I've seen are based on the table having some kind of unique identifier which keeps incrementing on each row, like an ID column.

I have a table that has a date and multiple values.

What I have is this:

```
  DATE            EU.1          
  2013-01-01      80 
  2013-01-08      82  
  2013-01-15      71
```

what I would like is:

```
  DATE            EU.1        Diff 
  2013-01-01      80          0
  2013-01-08      82          2
  2013-01-15      71         -10
```

Ultimately, I'd like to create a view that shows the difference in value between the most recent EU.1 value and the previous date.

Comment: Of course, you also have a unique identifier. In this case, it's the date... And the value!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am a fan of using correlated subqueries for this purpose.  In your case, this would be applied as:

```
select t.*,
       (`EU.1` - (select `EU.1`
                  from table t2
                  where t2.date < t.date
                  order by t2.date desc
                  limit 1
                 )
       ) as diff
from table t;
```

The only difference is that the first value will be `NULL` instead of `0` -- which makes more sense to me.  If you want `0`, use `coalesce()` around the whole expression.

Comment: Thanks for that Gordon, I've tested that and it works. I've also tried the one by Joachim, but his takes 18 seconds to run, whereas yours runs sub-second.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LEFT JOIN`. For each row, find the the immediately previous row by making sure there is no row between them; then just subtract.

```
SELECT c.date, c.eu1, COALESCE(c.eu1-a.eu1,0) diff
FROM mytable c
LEFT JOIN mytable a ON a.date < c.date
LEFT JOIN mytable b ON a.date < b.date AND b.date < c.date
WHERE b.date IS NULL;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8600/1).